# MySQL string manipulation for correct joining

Tags: mysql, string

I need to join two tables that have stored the same name but written differently. In one table, table1.name = 'A Jameson' and the other, table2.name = 'Anthony Jameson'. I have managed to join both tables using this in a query:

```
...
join table1 on substring_index(table1.name,' ',-1) like substring_index(table2.name,' ',-1)
...
```

But, obviously it returns everyone with matching surname ('James Jameson', 'Carl Jameson', etc). 

Is there a way of taking the longest string (table2) and shortening the first name to a initial?
 so 'Anthony Jameson' converts to 'A Jameson', and then matching for a join.
 This is further complicated by the fact that there are names with 3 words, like 'Craig B Henderson' or 'Jolly Mary Bethelem'.
 Ideally all the name except for surname (last word) should be converted to initials. So, 'Craig B Henderson' -> 'C B Henderson' and 'Jolly Mary Bethelem' -> 'J M Bethelem'.

Thanks

Comment: Wow, your table design has to be a nightmare to work with.,

Comment: +1, would like to see how you going to fix this

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a regular expression and then using the REGEXP operator to find it in your database table.

Documentation here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Otherwise you might have to process it after pulling your result set out.

Comment: I think it's quite complicated even with regular expressions.